# Trouble using dplyr::order to rank values from smallest to largest including positive integers smaller than 1

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, ranking

I'm want to rank the euclid_dist of combinations, grouped by pitch_2 in my dataframe from smallest to largestg. My dataframe has over 80million combinations a bunch of different pitch_2s which is my I'm grouping them by that. But the ordering seems almost random where the smallest euclid_dist isn't getting the #1 rank when I look at my data. I thought maybe it was an issue of some being below 1 and it was starting the counting then but it doesn't even work for values larger than 1.

This is the command I'm running to do the ranking

```
data <- data %>% group_by(pitch_2) %>% 
  mutate(rank = order(euclid_dist))
```

but this is what my dataframe looks like afterwards -- it correctly starts at 1 for each pitch_2 when ranking but the rankings themselves are out of whack and I'm not sure how to modify order or whether there is a better approach

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   pitch_2 [1]
  pitch_1   pitch_2   euclid_dist  rank
  <fct>     <fct>           <dbl> <int>
1 429721-CU 493247-SI        2.53    15
2 114849-FC 493247-SI        3.52     6
3 430599-FF 493247-SI        3.49    14
4 458567-FF 493247-SI        2.59    27
5 435261-CU 493247-SI        3.10     8
6 425629-CU 493247-SI        2.14    17
```

Comment: I think you need `rank(euclid_dist)` instead of `order`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `rank` instead of `order`.  According to `?rank`

> Returns the sample ranks of the values in a vector.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
       group_by(pitch_2) %>% 
       mutate(rank = order(euclid_dist))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   pitch_2 [1]
#  pitch_1   pitch_2   euclid_dist  rank
#  <chr>     <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
#1 429721-CU 493247-SI        2.53     2
#2 114849-FC 493247-SI        3.52     6
#3 430599-FF 493247-SI        3.49     5
#4 458567-FF 493247-SI        2.59     3
#5 435261-CU 493247-SI        3.1      4
#6 425629-CU 493247-SI        2.14     1
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(pitch_1 = c("429721-CU", "114849-FC", "430599-FF", 
"458567-FF", "435261-CU", "425629-CU"), pitch_2 = c("493247-SI", 
"493247-SI", "493247-SI", "493247-SI", "493247-SI", "493247-SI"
), euclid_dist = c(2.53, 3.52, 3.49, 2.59, 3.1, 2.14), rank = c(15L, 
6L, 14L, 27L, 8L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```